# self-supporting walls

Tags: walls, ceiling

I need to build some dividing walls, but per landlord requirements, these cannot reach the ceiling (must be 12" below the 100" high ceiling) to prevent re-working the existing sprinklers.

The floor is concrete & I can secure to side walls and floor.
The newly created space will need to have a door, so the walls need to support the door and minimal decor (pictures).

It seems to me that securing to the side walls and concrete floor should be sufficient, but I'd appreciate feedback or to bring-up concerns that I haven't considered.

Thanks!
Casara

Comment: What is the distance between the side walls?

Comment: In other words how long is this self supporting wall from end to end?

Comment: It might have some flex in the middle of the room. It would sure by nice to have a few brackets that tie it to the ceiling. Maybe that would be allowed as opposed to a solid wall going all the way to the ceiling.

Comment: The distance between walls varies (multiple areas being built out) but the longest wall is 13ft.  Is there a way to upload the floorplan design to this site to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply ask if you can have two beams on each wall that hit the ceiling.  These could span to the 1/3 mark on the walls and would keep it from flexing.  Simple 4x4 would probably look the best and should still pass fire code.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can justify a cross-wall that would make the structure self-standing...

Answer (score -1):

First, an answer because I realize some people just cannot get this stuff.  If it were me, I would build the wall like normal with a continuous double 2x4 top plate and just shoot about 6 +/- nails with our gun through the top section of the studs into the drywall.

Second, a thought.  What would the weight be from on that wall.  Maybe a person pushing off the wall to push a piece of furniture or something?  Rough housing and playing?  Door slamming?  Point is it might be upwards of 100 lb or something, maybe a bit more, but probably not 1000's.  And that weight is not at the top of wall so the weight is split to the top plate above (acting like a beam), then into the intersecting walls, and also into the floor, and that weight is for a short duration so deflection (bending of the wall) is the issue.

Now, what size the top plate is needed depends on the length of the wall.  You need a continuous top plate (no breaks) to be able to hold 75-100lb min. and you need the ends to be affixed to the intersection wall in such a way that each end can support about 75-100lb +/- of force.  What size top plate depends on length.  at 8'-10' a double 2x4 can actually easily hold that weight if we run it as a beam.  A single 2x4 actually can carry such a load.  Given it is a wall and not a beam (different duration), you are probably safe to span a double 2x4 upwards of 16' plus if you can get it a continuous span.  Less with splices, more if you are OK with it bending when you push on it.  A few options if you are longer or want less bending are build a 2x6 wall with a double 2x6 top plate or make it a triple 2x4 top plate.

Now for the ends.  Just screwing into drywall (not hitting a stud or blocking) if the wall is tight to the intersecting wall should be fine.  I know it sounds crazy but drywall screws into drywall in shear do have reliable strength.  [See Testing Here](http://www.grabberman.eu/Media/TechnicalData/450.pdf)  You can easily say each drywall screw can handle 20lb working load in shear so 4-5 screws or 6+ nails driven through the top section of the end stud into the drywall, with a couple nails driven down through the top plate in to the end studs will be plenty to hold the wall soundly.  Add more screws for end strength.

Again, if it were me, I would build the wall with a continuous double 2x4 top plate like normal and just shoot 6 +/- nails with our gun through the top section of the studs into the drywall and a few more nails in pairs down the length of the end studs.